# Is it secure to process an equation in this manner?

Tags: php, regex

I'm taking a user provided string like 'm*0.2' where 'm' is `$value` and evaluating the string. The user is allowed to use the 4 basic math operators, decimals, and negative numbers. Any attempt to use anything else is omitted.

```
$equation = $metric['formatter'];

$equation = preg_replace("/[^0-9*m.\/\+\-]/", "", $equation); //strips extra params

if (strlen($equation) > 1) {
    $equation = str_replace("m", ' $value ', $equation);

    $code = '$newValue = '.$equation.';';

    if (validExec($code)) { //validates syntax
        eval($code);

        $newValue = (int) $newValue; //unnecessary security step?

        if ($newValue != 0) {
            $value = $newValue;
        }
    }
}

function validExec($code) {
    $code = escapeshellarg('<?php ' . $code . ' ?>');

    $lint = 'echo $code | php -l'; // command-line PHP

    // maybe there are other messages for good code?
    return (preg_match('/No syntax errors detected in -/', $lint));
}
```

I want to know if my method is 100% secure in allowing the above to run.

Comment: Catching errors in eval'd statements is problematic and hacky at best. I would look at some math parsing libraries.

Comment: [ircmaxell's math evaluator library](https://gist.github.com/ircmaxell/1232629) is getting a bit old now; but it still works well, and is far safer than using eval

Comment: Wow. This is not just eval, but double eval: php and shell!

Comment: You haven't escaped the * and . chars in your regex, implying you've not done any testing on your code. You've used the wrong quoting characters for command line execution. The approach is valid but the way you are working is far from secure.

Comment: @symcbean `*` and `.` don't need to be escaped in a character class.

Comment: @symcbean - I don't know regex - this was just an initial attempt - which is why I came here. However, I don't believe those characters need escaping? Which characters should I use for command line execution? "? What's better about that?

Comment: @MarkBaker I looked at it yesterday - It's a bit heavier code wise than I'd like, but I will use it if my usage of eval is dangerous?

Comment: Not a real exploit yet, but I can read variables you didn't expect: `m123` runs the code `$newValue = $value123;`.

Comment: @melpomene Good catch

Comment: I can access operators you didn't expect: `++`, `--`, `**`, `.` (e.g. `m.m.m` runs `$newValue =  $value . $value . $value ;`).

Comment: @melpomene Another good catch. Seems only harmful to the user though? If they want to increment/decrement $value it doesn't really matter, but we are getting hacky here.

Comment: If you wanna assert correct formulas and whitelist a bit more precisely, then use a recursive regex. There's even a sample in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php#107377 (though could be simpler).

Comment: @mario Thanks for the tip - I'll attempt a more basic version of that.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at fixing code that eval'ed user inputted formulae as well.

What you are doing seems to prevent any user malicious code from being run on your server, as they would only be allowed the letter m, numbers and maths operators.

However, it just requires one bright spark to find a way around it, to compromise your system and I think most will agree that allowing user input to be eval'ed is probably not good practice, no matter how much you validate it.

When I was looking into my issue, I started looking for formulae processing libraries, such as those used in spreadsheets.
An Excel like library would take mathematical expressions and be able to safely evaluate them.

I never got around to testing that, but hopefully, if you can find the right one, you can even get backwards compatibility with your existing formulae.

Good luck.